# How to have a UIScrollView fit its content size, up until a max before scrolling in autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I want to create a UIScrollView in **autolayout** that will fully contain it's content (does not scroll) until the content is a certain size (say 400), and then it starts scrolling.

So I have my views laid out like this[image: UIScrollView]

If I set `Scroll View.height = ContentView.height`, then the scrollview expands to fit all of the content. So far so good.

Now if I try to set a max height via  `Scroll View.height <= 400`, what ends up happening is it sets the `ContentView.height` as well (due to `Scroll View.height = ContentView.height`) and the text becomes cut off and it doesn't scroll

[image: cut off text]

So is this even possible to do with autolayout? This seems easy to do with frames but I'd like a solution in autolayout.

Here's the sample project if you'd like to play around yourself - https://github.com/iwllyu/content-hugging-uisv-with-max

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a `UITextView` instead of a scroll view with a multiline `UILabel` in it?

Comment: I could use a UITextView - I suppose I can set a max height on that and it just gets taken care of?

Comment: Actually, nevermind... I think using a `UITextView` would present its own problems as well. There's no way to use *just* autolayout to make a text view expand to fit its content, so maybe using a `UILabel` really is best in this situation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have got everything else right.
But for this to work you should set priority of `Scroll View.height = ContentView.height` constraint less than the compression resistance priority of your subview (i.e. `UILabel` here).

So in your case anything below 750 will work.

Comment: Awesome! I had the priority on the max height set to 1000 and the priority on the equal height set to 750 with default values for the compression resistance property. 

I thought they were just relative to each other, not also to the hugging/compression priorities.

Thanks!